# Is this "alternate" Quadratic formula correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Quadratic Function.

$$ax^2 + bx + c = y $$

Deriving formula for x:

$ax^2 + bx + c = y$

$x^2 + \frac{bx}{a} + \frac{c}{a} = \frac{y}{a}$

$x^2 + \frac{bx}{a} = \frac{y}{a} - \frac{c}{a}$

$x^2 + \frac{bx}{a} + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}  = \frac{y}{a} - \frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}$

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{y}{a} - \frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}  $

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{y}{a} + \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}  $

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2+4ay-4ac}{4a^2}  $

$x + \frac{b}{2a} = \sqrt{\frac{b^2+4ay-4ac}{4a^2}}  $

$ x = \sqrt{\frac{b^2+4ay-4ac}{4a^2}} - \frac{b}{2a} $

$ x = \frac{-b +\sqrt{b^2+4ay-4ac}}{2a} $

$ x = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2+4ay-4ac}}{2a} $

Comment: It's essentially correct, but with a minor error. In the step where you take square roots of both sides, you need plus or minus on the result of the RHS. Other than that, it's correct, but see my answer for a simpler way.

Comment: Here's an alfernative formula just for fun: $$\frac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$$

Comment: That looks like the usual quadratic formula to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need all that.

Regarding $y$ as constant, and assuming $a \ne 0$, just use the ordinary quadratic formula to solve for $x$ in the equation
$$ax^2 + bx + (c-y)=0$$
which gives
$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c-y)}}{2a}$$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If $a=0$ then the function isn’t really quadratic anymore, just linear, in which case the standard quadratic formula wouldn’t hold either.

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor  Yes, I did not see this word. Thank you!

Comment: @quasi What happens if $b^2-4a(c-y)<0$? I think by your formula we'll get four roots.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: For a fixed value of $y$, you still get at only two roots.

Comment: @quasi I don't agree with you! For example, in $\mathbb C$ we have $\sqrt{-4}=\{-2i,2i\}$ and by your formula we'll get four roots: $2i$, $2i$, $-2i$ and $-2i$, which is not so true for the quadratic polynomial.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: In the context of this problem (algebra-precalculus), $\sqrt{-4}$ is just $2i$. The plus or minus is supplied by the formula itself.

Comment: @quasi But also $(-2i)^2=-4$. If some reasoning is wrong then  it's wrong without any relation with any context. I think.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Sure, $-4$ has two square roots $2i$ and $-2i$, but by convention, at the precalculus level, the square root symbol returns only one of them, namely $2i$. It's the same with $\sqrt{9}$. While $9$ has two square roots, $3$ and $-3$, the expression $\sqrt{9}$ is defined as $3$, not $\pm 3$.

Comment: @quasi In real numbers $\sqrt9=3$, but in complex numbers $\sqrt{9}=\{3,-3\}$. I think it's very smooth. The convention about it you said, I think, it's a very bad convention. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: In any standard precalculus text, the square root symbol is not a multi-valued expression. Definitions are allowed to change at a higher level (e.g., complex analysis).

Comment: @quasi I know, but for the right thinking we need to define things without lies. The fact that $\sqrt{-4}=2i$, but $\sqrt{2i}=\{1+i,-1-i\}$ it's an example of  the crude lie. I think.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Not really. Definitions are context dependent.